# Can i turn off wildcard expansion in cmd?

Tags: c, windows, cmd, command-line

I am working on a project to implement the dir command of cmd in C language.

When running a program written in c language in cmd, entering arguments containing * automatically converts it to a matching file.

How do I turn this off? or can you write a code that avoids this with c?

However, I would like to make the input format exactly the same as the existing dir command if possible dir command.

This question was written in a translator, so I would appreciate it if you could consider any awkward expressions. :)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("%d\n", argc);
    for(int i=0; argv[i] != NULL; i++)
        puts(argv[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

`find find.*`

When i try this code, there's only one result comes

Comment: This is more a shell question. Read https://askubuntu.com/questions/493749/prevent-parameter-expansion-in-shell-script

Comment: OT: You can probably do: `find "find.*"` or `find 'find.*'` but that's more a workaround than a solution

Comment: Related but probably not exactly what you are looking for https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/519560/144237

Comment: OT: You have posted a lot of code. I don't think all that code is needed. The following short program should show your problem: `int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n", argc);
    for(int i=0; argv[i] != NULL; i++) puts(argv[i]);
    return 0;
}` When posting question here at SO it's a good idea to reduce your code to a minimum that shows the problem.

Comment: And you should tell us the shell used. Is it on windows? Version? Is it linux? Whisch shell type?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm running from a command prompt in Windows.

Comment: IIRC on Windows the shell is not responsible for this, this feature gets compiled into the application.

Comment: If so, is the compiler the cause? Is there a macro or other compiler to fix this issue?

Comment: What result do you exactly obtain?

Comment: If a string containing wildcard characters is given as an argument, the arguments are replaced by the file name with the fastest alphabetical name in ascending order. I want to turn off this option.

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/504809/144237

Comment: But that's bash and I have to run it on command prompt...

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: For MinGW or MinGW-w64 there is an object file called "CRT_noglob.o" in its lib directory. You can link that with your executable to disable wildcard expansion. For example, if compiling from an MSYS2 MinGW bash shell, `gcc find.c $MSYSTEM_PREFIX/lib/CRT_noglob.o -o find`.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows `cmd.exe` is not responsible for glob expansions. Instead it's each executable's responsibility to do it if it wants to. Normally, when building with MSVC, this happens inside the C Runtime (CRT) initialization code before it enters into your `main` function (on Windows console apps `main` is not the actual entry point; it's `mainCRTStartup` that's implemented by the CRT).

I don't know of a way to disable this feature while still having the standard C `main` as an entry point. However, you can still access the un-processed command line using the [`GetCommandLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinea) function from WinAPI, or the [`_acmdln`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/acmdln-tcmdln-wcmdln?view=msvc-170) global variable provided by the CRT. In either case those will give you the entirety of the command line in one un-split string. You'll need to split the arguments manually, including handling quotes and so on. This, however, sounds like what your exercise is about.